# value in structure changes after closing a for loop

Tags: c, for-loop, struct

Short Version: Why does `(compounds+k)->spectra->peaks` change after the `for` loops iteration (in 4 out of ~2500 compounds)?

Long Version: I have a function that examines all my data (in the structure chromatogram (`chrom`)) and adds those of `type == 1` straight to a new structure (`compounds`), chromatograms of `type == 2` are examined if there are highly similar chromatograms in the remaining data and summed/averaged into 1 entry of `compounds`. This program worked fine when I originally wrote it with the datasets I had at the time but with recent data I ran into a bug where the integer that tracks howmany 'values' are in a spectrum somehow is reset to 0 AFTER the encompassing `for loop` ends. I hope that it'll be a bit clearer after reading my code (take special note of the 2 prints at the end which demonstrate the issue).

```
chromatogram*
spectral_matcher(chromatogram* chrom, arguments* args) {
   int i, j, k = 0, l, m, size, counter = 0;
   float low_mass, high_mass, low_time, high_time;
   chromatogram* compounds;
   compounds = calloc(MAX_SPECTRA,sizeof(chromatogram));
   for (i = 0; i < chrom->hits-1; i++) {
       if ( (chrom+i)->type == 1) {
           /* Adding the MS1 spectrum to output set */
           chrom_copy(chrom, compounds, i, k);
           k++;
       } else if ((chrom+i)->used != 1 && (chrom+i)->type == 2) {
           /* Adding the MSn spectrum to output set */
           chrom_copy(chrom, compounds, i, k);
           /* Acquiring search paramenters */
           low_mass = (chrom+i)->precursor - args->mass_tolerance;
           high_mass = (chrom+i)->precursor + args->mass_tolerance;
           low_time = (chrom+i)->time - args->time_tolerance;
           high_time = (chrom+i)->time + args->time_tolerance;
           /* Performing search for matching spectra */
           for (j = i+1; j < chrom->hits; j++) {
               if ( (chrom+j)->type == 2 && (chrom+j)->precursor > low_mass && (chrom+j)->precursor < high_mass && (chrom+j)->time > low_time && (chrom+j)->time < high_time && (chrom+i)->spectra->peaks > 10 && (chrom+j)->spectra->peaks > 10 && (chrom+j)->used != 1) {
                   /* the KS test can only be performed if the previous if statement was true */
                   if (pdf_ks((chrom+i)->pdf,(chrom+j)->pdf, 1.0) == 1) {
                       if (args->verbose == 1) {
                           printf("Matching spectrum %i with %i into %i\n",i, j, k);
                       }
                       // De magicks - Photo Finish
                       counter++;
                       l = (compounds+k)->spectra->peaks;
                       size = (compounds+k)->spectra->peaks + (chrom+j)->spectra->peaks;
                       (compounds+k)->spectra->peaks = size;
                       m = 0;
                       /* `l` is at the end of original spectra, append values starting from `l` */
                       for (; l < size; l++) {
                           ((compounds+k)->spectra+l)->mz_value = ((chrom+j)->spectra+m)->mz_value;
                           ((compounds+k)->spectra+l)->int_value = ((chrom+j)->spectra+m)->int_value;
                           m++;
                       }
                       // set the 'matched' spectrum to NULL so there will be no duplicates
                       (chrom+j)->used = 1;
                   }
               }
           }
           k++;
       }
       /* k was incremented in either the if or else if so doing -1 here */
       printf("%i: values [ %i ] contains a value set [ %f - %f ]\n", k-1, (compounds+k-1)->spectra->peaks, ((compounds+k-1)->spectra+5000)->mz_value,((compounds+k-1)->spectra+5000)->int_value);
   }
   printf("BREAKPOINT\n");
   printf("%i spectra summed\n",counter);
   compounds->hits = k;
   for (i = 0; i < compounds->hits; i++) {
       printf("%i: values [ %i ] contains a value set [ %f - %f ]\n", i, (compounds+i)->spectra->peaks, ((compounds+i)->spectra+5000)->mz_value,((compounds+i)->spectra+5000)->int_value);
   }
   exit(0);
   return(compounds);
}
```

I know that 4 compounds give the strange behaviour that I explained earlier so here are the matching lines from the output:

```
736: values [ 16481 ] contains a value set [ 765.000000 - 0.000000 ]
847: values [ 16481 ] contains a value set [ 765.000000 - 5843.000000 ]
1810: values [ 16481 ] contains a value set [ 765.000000 - 0.000000 ]
2212: values [ 16481 ] contains a value set [ 765.000000 - 0.000000 ]
BREAKPOINT
736: values [ 0 ] contains a value set [ 765.000000 - 905.625000 ]
847: values [ 0 ] contains a value set [ 765.000000 - 905.625000 ]
1810: values [ 0 ] contains a value set [ 765.000000 - 905.625000 ]
2212: values [ 0 ] contains a value set [ 765.000000 - 905.625000 ]
```

The values in the array even seem to be change based on the results of this.

The values around the 4 peculiar ones remain correct however:

```
735: values [ 44801 ] contains a value set [ 556.250000 - 0.000000 ]
736: values [ 16481 ] contains a value set [ 765.000000 - 0.000000 ]
737: values [ 131848 ] contains a value set [ 765.000000 - 0.000000 ]
BREAKPOINT
735: values [ 44801 ] contains a value set [ 556.250000 - 0.000000 ]
736: values [ 0 ] contains a value set [ 765.000000 - 905.625000 ]
737: values [ 131848 ] contains a value set [ 765.000000 - 0.000000 ]
```

I would really appreciate if anyone have any hits or tips on what next to check.

**-- May 16th (4:20) --**

I tried seeing where the data changes by manually breaking the for loop at a specific `i` value by adding `if (i == 806) { break; }` to the code. This yielded:

```
736: values [ 16481 ] contains a value set [ 765.000000 - 0.000000 ]
BREAKPOINT
736: values [ 0 ] contains a value set [ 765.000000 - 905.625000 ]
```

**-- May 17th --**

I also checked if the i and k counters are doing something strange but they seem perfectly fine (inside the for loop):

```
I: 803  K: 734
I: 804  K: 735
I: 805  K: 736 /* The iteration which shows wrong data AFTER the for loop closes */
I: 806  K: 737
I: 807  K: 738
I: 808  K: 739
```

Comment: nobody expect here a paragraph as a question.Please make sure you write in what you want to ask only.

Comment: I would if the question was easy, the shortest way possible (but not entirely correct) would be the part that i added as a TL:DR

Comment: Maybe you should also cross-check whether `printf("%i: %i\n", k-1, (compounds+k-1)->spectra->peaks);` within loop and `printf("%i: %i\n",i, (compounds+i)->spectra->peaks);` after your BREAKPOINT refer to same locations within the array

Comment: The values in the array for the strange values are changed, the values in the array before and after are correct however (ie scan compound 735 and 737 are the same in both priints).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was appending past the space allocated to spectra (in the part commented by photo finish), I would have expected valgrind to give a message of writing past buffer but the error I got was free of invalid pointer later on.

The problem was solved by increasing the value of `MAX_PEAKS`

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this:

```
chromatogram* compounds;
compounds = calloc(MAX_SPECTRA,sizeof(compound));
```

Did you perhaps mean `sizeof(chromatogram)`? Or `compound *compounds`?

Comment: it should be the first yes but this isn't the cause of the 'problem' that I am having (still +1 for spotting that inconsistency).

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you change the value of `(compounds+k)->spectra->peaks`?

```
size = (compounds+k)->spectra->peaks + (chrom+j)->spectra->peaks;
(compounds+k)->spectra->peaks = size;
```

The `size` variable is an `int`, which might have something to do with your problem.

Comment: No, peaks is an int that keeps track of howmany spectra there are. The chunk that you list is supposed to add the 2 ints since I add the entire spectra belonging to (chrom+j) to (compounds+k)

Comment: Ahh, I'm sorry, the code is a little hard to follow! I see it now.

Comment: I hoped that the 'Long Version' in my original question made it clear what it is supposed to do :(